# How do I delete a row form SQLite DB via ListView and refresh list view?

Tags: android, sqlite, fetch, delete-row

I have a list that gets its values ​​from the database .

For each of the items I put a delete button .
When the user clicks the button, the item is removed .
My problem is that I do not know how to refresh the list after deletion...

I already have a database created in the folder assets.

Only problem I delete and refresh the list

class QusitionActivity:

```
public class QusitionActivity extends Activity {
  String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/mmm" + "/"+"HOME";
  String[]qustion;
  ListView list;
  Myadapter adapter;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_qusition);
    SQLiteDatabase dataBase=openOrCreateDatabase(path, MODE_PRIVATE, null); 
    Cursor cursor=dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT qustion,position FROM List_qusition;"
                                    , null);
    qustion=new String[cursor.getCount()];
    int i=0;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
         qustion[i]=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("qustion"));     
        i++;
    }

    dataBase.close();
     list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter=new Myadapter(getApplicationContext());
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
}
```

class Myadapter:

```
public class Myadapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater myInflater;
    public Myadapter(Context context) {
        myInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return qustion.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ViewHolder Holder;
      if(convertView==null) {
            Holder=new ViewHolder();
            convertView=myInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_custom_layout,null );
            Holder.qustion=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_qustion);
            Holder.delete=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_delete);
            Holder.qustion.setText(qustion[position]);
            Holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SQLiteDatabase dataBase=openOrCreateDatabase(path,
                                                             MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                dataBase.execSQL("DELETE FROM List_qusition WHERE position="
                                 +(position+1) +";");
                dataBase.close();
                //  Delete_item(position);
             }
            });
            convertView.setTag(Holder);
      } else {
            Holder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

class ViewHolder

```
public class ViewHolder extends Activity {
    TextView qustion;
    Button delete;
}
```

Comment: call notifyDatasetChanged() from your adapter after deletion

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [`CursorLoader`](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html) and a `CursorAdapter`.

It will automatically update when your database is changed. As it is now, there's no way your list will know that you've deleted a row - even if you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, it will only look into a list which stays the same.

At least you could query a new cursor and load its data into a list and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. However I really advise you not to.

Answer (score 0):

Call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter. This updates the list based on the new values in the database.

The full documentation for the BaseAdapter that you're extending can be found here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

Comment: Thanks ..
I know have used the above function .but How and where do I put the program to work correctly.